# QGraphicsItem::toGraphicsObject() returns 0 in own class derived by QGraphicsPixmapItem

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qgraphicsitem

At the moment im trying to get items from my own QGraphicsView what is derived by :QObject, and :QGraphicsPixmapItem. So i added 2 items to my scene and now i want this items to get them out in another method with a `QList <QGraphicsItem*>` but unfortunately it does not work well and `QGraphicsItem::toGraphicsObject()` returns 0.

So i found this description in the Qt-Reference-Documentation:

```
QGraphicsObject * QGraphicsItem::toGraphicsObject ()

Return the graphics item cast to a QGraphicsObject, if the class is actually a
graphics object, 0 otherwise.
```

Because i want to animate the item what i want to get out from my `itemList` and want to `setTargetObject` for `myAnimation`. But this method needs a `QGraphicsObject` so thats why i need to convert it to. Hope my sourcecode tells a bit more:

**-- A.h --**

```
class A : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY (QPointF pos READ pos WRITE setPos)

public:
    A()
    {
        setTransformationMode (Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    }

    QPointF itemPos;
};
```

**-- A.cpp--**

```
void A::method()
{
    QList <QGraphicsItem*> itemList = myGraphicsView -> items();

    QGraphicsObject *test = itemList.at (0) -> toGraphicsObject();

    qDebug() << test; // <-- QGraphicsObject(0)

    myAnimation -> setTargetObject (test);
    myAnimation -> setPropertyName ("pos");
    myAnimation -> setStartValue (QPointF (0, 100));
    myAnimation -> setEndValue (QPointF (60, 100));

    myAnimation -> start();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a `QGraphicsObject` is a specific class by itself. You can not create a new class from `QObject` and any of the `QGraphicsItems` and use it as a `QGraphicsObject`. The two aren't even on the same class hierarchy. So you can't cast one to the other.

Secondly, `setTargetObject` takes an `QObject`, not `QGraphicsObject`. So you can get your object, which is a `QObject`, this way:

```
A *test = dynamic_cast<A*>(itemList.at(0));
```

`setTargetObject` will happily take it.